# Conflict with click and hover animation Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a little problem with my jQuery code.

Here is my code :

```
$("#bloc-search").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("bloc-search-highlight");
        //var jObj = $( this );
});

if ( $("#formulaire-search").is(':visible')){   

    $('.search').attr('src', '/img/search-blanc.png');

} else {

    $("#bloc-search").hover(
        function(){
           $('.search').attr('src', '/img/search-blanc.png');
        }, function(){
           $('.search').attr('src', '/img/search-blue.png');
    });

}
```

It works almost perfectly, but my problem is when my #formulaire-search is visible the hover function is still working and i don't know why because in my if i don't have the hover function.
I also tried with the hasClass instead of visible no way...

An idea ?

Thank you for your help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
if ( $("#formulaire-search").is(':visible')){
  $("#bloc-search").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
  ... other stuff ...
} else {
  $("#bloc-search").bind('mouseenter mouseleave'); // to be sure
  ... other stuff ...
}
```

You might have to rebind it then when you need hover functionality

**UPDATE**

This works as it should - using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` works well and can also work natively just as easy

```
if ( $("#formulaire-search").is(':visible')){   

    $('.search').attr('src', '/img/search-blanc.png');

} else {

    // do what you want here - only works when #formulaire-search not visible     
    $("#bloc-search").on('mouseenter', function(){
           $(this).addClass('goTeal');
    });

    $("#bloc-search").on('mouseleave', function(){
           $(this).removeClass('goTeal');
    });

}
```

[Here's a fiddle to look at](https://jsfiddle.net/c7ctvb51/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still not working.  Even with your idea :  

`if ( $("#formulaire-search").is(':visible')){     
 $("#bloc-search").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');  
    $('.search').attr('src', '/img/search-blanc.png');  
} else {  
 $("#bloc-search").bind('mouseenter mouseleave');  
    $("#bloc-search").hover(  
        function(){  
           $('.search').attr('src', '/img/search-blanc.png');  
        }, function(){  
           $('.search').attr('src', '/img/search-blue.png');  
    });  
}`

Comment: Hi Darren, i tried with your update (mouseenter, mouseleave) and it's still not working. I don't know why the mouseenter and the mouseleave are still active whereas the div is visible :-(

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle I made? that works as it should so if yours is not then I suspect something else is causing it to fail - are there ant console errors?

Comment: I checked your fiddle and on different computer and browser there is no animation. I have no errors in the console.